# Creating links in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, gallery, hyperlink

I have a gallery script where, as a newbie, I was successful in creating thumbnails. I am able to click on the thumbnail to get the large image, but when I press 'next' for the next image, I get a *'zero' image found* message. This gallery runs on 'photo_caption' as the primary key.

Here is the bit of code I have trouble with...

```php
$result_final .= "<div class='prevnext'>"; 
            $result_final .= "<span class='prev'><a href=viewgallery.php?cname=$cname&pcaption=".str_replace(" ","_",$pid_array[$next])."><img src=photos/assets/left.png  border=0 ></a></span>"; 
            $result_final .= "<span class='next'><a href=viewgallery.php?cname=$cname&pcaption=".str_replace(" ","_",$pid_array[$prev])."><img src=photos/assets/right.png  border=0 ></a></span>"; 
            $result_final .= "</div>";
```

Here the 'left' and the 'right' arrows are created, but when I click on them it is not taking me to the next image. If I try to print `$nr` ( number of rows corresponding to the photo_caption that's being clicked, which is equal to '1' ) it becomes '0' when I click on the 'next' arrow for the next image. Is this because the link is not working? Can you please check my code to see if I am making any stupid mistakes while creating the link? See the full code of that section below.

```php
if( $pcaption ) 
    { 

        $result = mysql_query( "SELECT photo_caption, photo_description, photo_filename,photo_keywords FROM gallery_photos WHERE photo_caption='".addslashes($pcaption)."'" ); 

        list($photo_caption, $photo_description, $photo_filename, $photo_keywords) = mysql_fetch_array( $result ); 

        $nr = mysql_num_rows( $result ); 
         mysql_free_result( $result );     

        $p_caption = $photo_caption;
        $p_description = $photo_description;
        $p_keywords = $photo_keywords;

        //fill pid_array with sorted pids in current category 

        $result = mysql_query( "SELECT photo_caption FROM gallery_photos WHERE category_name='".addslashes($cname)."' ORDER BY photo_caption" ); 

        $ct = mysql_num_rows( $result );     

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

              $pid_array[] = $row[0]; 
        } 
        mysql_free_result( $result ); 

        #if( empty($nr ) ) 
        if($nr <0)
        { 

            $result_final = "\t<tr><td>***No Photo found</td></tr>\n"; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            $result = mysql_query( "SELECT category_name FROM gallery_category WHERE category_name='".addslashes($cname)."'" ); 
            list($category_name) = mysql_fetch_array( $result ); 
            mysql_free_result( $result );     
            $result_final = "
            <div class=limagePage>
            <div class=llink><a href=viewgallery.php>ALBUMS</a><span class=arrow>&gt;&gt</span><a href=viewgallery.php?cname=$cname>$category_name</a></div>
             ";
            // display previous and next links if more than one photo 

            if ($ct > 1) 
            { 

                $key = array_search($pcaption , $pid_array); 
                $prev = $key - 1; 

                if ($prev < 0) $prev = $ct - 1; 
                $next = $key + 1; 

                if ($next == $ct) $next = 0; 

                $cname = str_replace(" ","_",$cname);
                $pcaption=str_replace(" ","_",$pcaption);

                $result_final .= "<div class='prevnext'>"; 
                $result_final .= "<span class='prev'><a href=viewgallery.php?cname=$cname&pcaption=".str_replace(" ","_",$pid_array[$next])."><img src=photos/assets/left.png  border=0 ></a></span>"; 
                $result_final .= "<span class='next'><a href=viewgallery.php?cname=$cname&pcaption=".str_replace(" ","_",$pid_array[$prev])."><img src=photos/assets/right.png  border=0 ></a></span>"; 
                $result_final .= "</div>";

            }            
        }
        $cname = str_replace(" ","_",$cname);
        $pcaption=str_replace(" ","_",$pcaption);
       $result_final .= "<div class=limage><table><tr><td><table class=image><tr>\n\t<td><a href=viewgallery.php?cname=$cname&pcaption=".str_replace(" ","_",$pid_array[$next])."><img src='".$images_dir."/".$photo_filename."' border='0' alt='".$photo_keywords."' /></a>
      <div class=caption>".$photo_caption."</div> 
      <div class='excerpt'>".$photo_description."</div> 
      </td>                    
      </tr></table></td></tr></table><div class=underline></div></div>
      <!-- .limagePage --></div>    ";

 }
```

Comment: Hover over the links and see what the links say. You could also use "View Source" to verify that the links go where they should. If not, it could help you (or us) figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Herbert... I have tried that right now...it looks like this...`<a href="viewgallery.php?cname=Simple_Expressions&pcaption=Waiting_Sunset">` to my understanding, it does point to an image in my database. But when I click it does not lead me to that image... completely baffled by this...I am thinking I made some profound mistakes in my code?  <a href="viewgallery.php?cname=Simple_Expressions&pcaption=Waiting_Sunset">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is messed up, that could be the problem, try putting '' suround the values of your html tags, like this:

```
<a href='viewgallery.php?cname=$cname&pcaption=".str_replace(" ","_",$pid_array[$prev])."'><img src='photos/assets/right.png' border='0'></a>
```

Comment: Thank you netsetter..I corrected my HTML now but it still not correcting the problem.

Comment: What exactly happens if you type `viewgallery.php?cname=Simple_Expressions&pcaption=Waiting_Sunset` manually in your browser? You have an error message or just seeying the wrong photo? And how the URI looks like with the photo you are looking before you click the next/previous button?

Comment: Netsetter...a combination of your answer and removing the `str_replace()` from the link helped to resolve this problem! :-) My HTML was messed up like you said. So my ink was all jumbled up hence I added `str_replace()` but removing that and cleaning up my HTML did the final magic...so thank you netsetter.I wish I could vote your answer up... I am new here and don't have enough reputation to do so!! Crazy..!

Comment: @yathrakaaran : I'm glad I could help you. I was already wondering about str_replace(), this would have been the next question but good you already found out yourself. Testing and fixing step by step often helps to get the code working. Have a nice day.